# Only one of my two network cards is working

Tags: 10.04, networking

I have a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server which has two Ethernet ports `eth0` and `eth1`.

- `eth0` is connected to ISP1 with network 192.168.3.0/24 with server static address 192.168.3. 5
- `eth1` is connected to ISP2 with network 192.168.5.0/24 with server static address 192.168.5.10

When `eth1` is connected, there is no internet connection from `eth0`.  The internal network is accessible, eg, ssh , ping  from other computers in 192.168.3.0/24 network.

When `eth1` is disabled or disconnected, `eth0` works just fine.

How can I ensure that both the Ethernet ports get internet connections?

**netstat configs eth1 disabled**

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface

192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0

0.0.0.0         192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

**Netstat config eth1 enabled**

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface

192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0

192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1

0.0.0.0         192.168.5.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1

0.0.0.0         192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

**Edit**

I have also checked /etc/resolv.conf

There, I have manually added the nameserver for both the gateways.

**ip addr show**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 11:bb:3e:15:3e:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.100/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global eth0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 100
    link/ether aa:2a:ae:5f:59:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.5.100/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global eth1
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Can you run `route -n`, both with eth0 enabled and with eth0 disabled, and add that to your question? It will both help visualize things and maybe spot problem areas.

Comment: @roadmr: done as requested.

Comment: anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: How are you testing that the internet is/isn't working on eth0? My suspicion is that, because both eth0 & eth1 have the same priority, the system is preferring to send packets on eth1. From your route table, anywhere other than the 2 local networks should be accessible from either gateway, so when a connection is received from the internet on eth0, the system sends the reply on eth1, expecting that it will get there. In theory, this should work. But if certain addresses can only be accessed via a particular ISP, you will need to add explicit routing.

Comment: i tested by taking out the ethernet cable. once eth1 was taken out, eth0 had no connection

Comment: I firmly believe that you can have only one default route (destination 0.0.0.0) working at any given time if the matric is same.If the metric is different, still one will get higher priority over other.  As per routing table you given, the priority is for eth1 gateway for 0.0.0.0 when both are enabled. Else you should be looking at load balancing two network interfaces to achieve accessing internet through both NICs. Have a look at this. http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html#AEN298

Comment: Are you sure it's not a nameserver problem? Can you ping the Google DNS? Does it work if you only put the Google DNS in the resolv.conf? Its IPv4 is 8.8.8.8

Comment: @Ubuntuser, are you using policy routing? If not, I think that this is what you are looking for. It will allow you to set up multiple routing tables. My understanding, is that you can only have one active default gateway in a routing table at a time without this. You will require linux kernel support for policy routing and also need the iproute2 utilities. http://serverfault.com/questions/291036/ubuntu-10-04-two-interfaces-on-a-same-subnet-with-a-same-gateway

Comment: @bseibold: yes it works if I only put 8.8.8.8. If I do a traceroute, it shows that the connection is going through eth1, never from eth0. there seems to be some sort of cacheing which takes place,and i cannot control that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a possible running example based on the basic implementation (of Split access) taken from [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html#AEN258).

Create two additional routing tables, say T1 and T2.

```
ip route add 192.168.3.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.3.5 table T1
ip route add default via 192.168.3.0/24 table T1
ip route add 192.168.5.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.5.10 table T2
ip route add default via 192.168.5.0/24 table T2
```

Set up the main routing table:

```
ip route add 192.168.3.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.3.5
ip route add 192.168.5.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.5.10
```

Add your preference for default route:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.3.5
```

Set up the routing rules, choose what routing table to route with.

```
ip rule add from 192.168.3.5 table T1
ip rule add from 192.168.5.10 table T2
```

More info [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html#AEN258).

Comment: thanks for your reply. but even after doing that, i get this `2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000` for `eth0`.  Should the state be `UNKNOWN` ?

Comment: @Ubuntuser - Disable the network manager or anything that could control these interfaces. Do you get the same error?

Comment: its a headless server with no gui installed, there is no network manager .

Comment: @Ubuntuser - Purge all IP configuration of the interfaces with `ip addr flush eth0 && ip addr flush eth1` and retry. Some useful info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html).

Comment: thanks. its not the perfect solution but I will take it. It works sometimes and other times it does not. But after research I found out thats the best I can get from this type of load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out that both ports are up. Reconfigure eth1, eth0 as always up.